# Terraform - having timing issues launching EC2 instance with instance profile

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I'm using Terraform to create my AWS infrastructure.

I've a module that creates an "aws_iam_role", an "aws_iam_role_policy", and an "aws_iam_instance_profile" and then launches an EC2 Instance with that aws_iam_instance_profile.

"terraform plan" works as expected, but with "terraform apply" I consistently get this error:

```
* aws_instance.this: Error launching source instance: InvalidParameterValue:   IAM Instance Profile "arn:aws:iam::<deleted>:instance-profile/<deleted>" has no associated IAM Roles
```

If I immediately rerun "terraform apply", it launches the EC2 instance with no problem.  If I run a "terraform graph", it does show that the instance is dependent on the profile.

Since the second "apply" is successful, that implies that the instance_policy and all that it entails is getting created correctly, doesn't it?

I've tried adding a "depends_on" and it doesn't help, but since the graph already shows the dependency, I'm not sure that is the way to go anyway.

Anyone have this issue?

Comment: Can you post up your tf file showing how these are glued together. I've run into some odd timing issues with terraform but those were SQS related rather than IAM...

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20157294/908390

Answer (score 1):

Race conditions are quite common between services - where state is only eventually consistent due to scale. This is particularly true with IAM where you will often create a role and give a service such as EC2 a trust relationship to use the role for an EC2 instance, but due to however IAM is propogated throughout AWS, the role will not be available to EC2 services for a few seconds after creation.

The solution I have used, which is not a great one but gets the job done, is to put the following provisioner on every single IAM role or policy attachment to give the change time to propagate:

```tf
resource "aws_iam_role" "some_role" {
    ...
    provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sleep 10"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you may use operation timeouts. Timeouts are handled entirely by the resource type implementation in the provider, but resource types offering these features follow the convention of defining a child block called timeouts that has a nested argument named after each operation that has a configurable timeout value. Each of these arguments takes a string representation of duration, such as "60m" for 60 minutes, "10s" for ten seconds, or "2h" for two hours.

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "example" {
  # ...

  timeouts {
    create = "60m"
    delete = "2h"
  }
}
```

Ref: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html