# How long for a new AWS policy to propagate when created from Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am using the Amazon Java SDK, it is used to do the following:

1. Create a group
2. Create a policy
3. Attach the policy to the group
4. Add an existing user to the group

This is done to give a user temporary access to a location in an S3 bucket. The problem is that after step #4, if I initiate an operation on behalf of the user, I can receive a 403 Forbidden message, because the user doesn't have access. If I had a `Thread.sleep()` call to delay things, and let them propagate, it seems to work. Sleeping for 1 second was too short, and 5 seconds was long enough.

Does anyone know if there is an official length of time required to let a new policy and group association propagate in AWS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience is it nearly instantaneous. There is a good discussion of the topic here:

[How long should I wait after applying an AWS IAM policy before it is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156043/how-long-should-i-wait-after-applying-an-aws-iam-policy-before-it-is-valid)

Comment: Thanks - I had searched for an existing question, but hadn't found this one. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I think it's fair to call this one a duplicate.  When I saw the question, I thought "this sounds familiar..."  Thanks for digging this one up.