# S3 full-access configuration from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've created a role to grant full access to S3 from an EC2 instance. This is working ok, every time I create a new EC2 instance and attach this role it has full access to all my buckets on S3. I feel this is quite insecure, so my question is: is it possible to create a role or something similar to grant EC2 instances full access to **specific** buckets on S3 and not to all of them? Thanks!

This is the role I have right now:

```
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

Comment: Already answered by me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49849060/2732674

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered by me [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49849060/2732674)

You can try this policy to give full access to a **particular bucket**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [{
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKETNAME>/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```