# AWS IAM / CMK propagation time

Tags: amazon-web-services

does someone know the IAM role propagation time? I am creating roles programmatically and then use them in KMS CMK setup. In 95% of the cases the role is available to KMS within less than a few seconds. However, in around 5% of cases it takes 5 seconds and more. Is there a know metric on the latency of the system? To my knowledge its eventual consistent so expect latency but what are the SLO?

Edit: found this

> after creating a role, it does take an indeterminate amount of time for that role to be available in a region. There is no way to programmatically determine when a role is available in region. The system is eventually consistent and times will vary depending on what you are trying to access. The best advice I could give you would be to wait at least 30-45 seconds for your first call and then use exponential backoff when retrying after an access denied.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=255063

This stackoverflow question is about IAM timeing in general but not fully informative: [How long should I wait after applying an AWS IAM policy before it is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156043/how-long-should-i-wait-after-applying-an-aws-iam-policy-before-it-is-valid?rq=1)

Comment: Post your finding as the answer.

Comment: well its not really satisfying... @vishal.k