# AWS how to check an IAM role is ready to use after created

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

in .Net, after I create IAM role, I need to wait very long (~20s) before I can create lambda function or Kinesis firehose using that IAM role.
Is there any way that I can check if IAM role is active to use? In my current code, I have to wait 20s. That is an unsafe solution because it may take longer than 20s until IAM role is active.

Comment: Create a loop and check if the role is ready ever 5 second or so. break the loop when its ready.

Comment: Create a loop and "check if the role is ready" => how to check if the role is ready? this is my problem @Marcin

Comment: What problem? You haven't show any code in which you attempt to write the loop. no errors nor any context on what you are doing and what is the problem with your code.

Comment: you instruct me to check if the role is ready, what is the code to do that? because my question is: what is the code to check if the role is ready @Marcin

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20157294/2570277

Comment: If you are creating a new IAM Role, just call `GetRole()`, passing the role name. If it doesn't (yet) exist, it will generate an error. To see what that error looks like, call it with an incorrect name. Then you'll know how to recognise a role that does, or doesn't, exist.

Comment: thanks @JohnRotenstein, but your solution doesn't work
`await client.CreateRoleAsync(roleName); // pass
        await client.PutRolePolicyAsync(roleName); // pass
        var roleARN = await client.GetRoleAsync(roleName); // pass
        await client.CreateDeliveryStreamAsync(roleARN); // fail`
mean GetRole() cannot be used to check if the role is active or not